# SwiftUI adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth equivalent

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, swiftui

I'm building an app in `SwiftUI` which contains a lot of components, including a `Text` view which contains a long string.

When I launch the app on iPhone 11 everything works perfectly, but when I launch it on a smaller device (iPhone SE for example), the `Text` view cuts the text in the middle, and shows three dots (...) instead of the rest of the text.

What would be the best solution for this? Is there an equivalent for `UILabel`'s `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` in `SwiftUI`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not exactly, but kind of...

```
Text("Your long next here")
   .minimumScaleFactor(0.2) // value is up to you
```

Comment: Thank you. That's work. Can you please explain what this `minimumScaleFactor` do?

Comment: @F.SO7, Option-click in Xcode editor on it and you'll see default documentation :), no needs to copy-paste it here.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a really large font size and use `func minimumScaleFactor(_ factor: CGFloat)` to let the text shrink. You can also add `lineLimit(1)` to force the text to be on one line.

```swift
Text("My long text adjusted to fit width")
    .font(.system(size: 200))
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.0001)
    .lineLimit(1)
```