# how to align top the text in this UILabel

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiview, uilabel

Why the justified text won't align top? there's `additional padding on top and bottom`. `I want the text to be aligned top` and `should only take the required space` for the length of the text. How to `fit the frame`? Deleting `height` will show only one line.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextWidget: View {
     
    private let view = UILabel()
        let justified: Bool
     
    var body: some View {
  
        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                       
            HStack (alignment: .top) {
                if justified {
                    JustifiedText("sampletext looonggg texttttsss dddddDDDDD dddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdd ")
                        .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
                        
                         
                }
            
            if !justified {
                Text("sampletext looonggg texttttsss dddddDDDDD dddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDDDDDdddddDD dddddDDDDD")
                    .font(Font.system(size: 25, weight: .regular ))
                    .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
            }
            }.background(Color.purple)
        }    .frame(width: 200,  height: 400, alignment: .top)
}
}

struct JustifiedText: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let value: String
    init(_ string: String) {
        value = string
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.textAlignment = .justified
        view.numberOfLines = 0
         view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        view.text = value
        view.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
        view.allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = false
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
         
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

*Edit:* someone suggested a similar post, but it does not `justify the text`. `justifying text` and maintaining `font size` is a main requirement.

Comment: I think you should start from stopping mixing UIKit and SwiftUI

Comment: @Cy-4AH then how to justify text in swiftui? do you know any method? if not I must mix them together :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427991/swiftui-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth-equivalent)

Comment: @Cy-4AH it doesn't justify text. justifying text and maintaining text size is a main requirement.