# How to stop text from clipping with certain fonts

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
  ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.yellow)
                .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .shadow(radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)

            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(Date(), style: .time)
                    .font(.custom(font.code, size: 28))
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(textColor)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.bottom, 3)   
              
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
        }
```

But depending on which font I select, the text gets cut off at the top. Is there a way to stop this?

The two fonts used in this example are Academy Engraved LET (top) and Rockwell (bottom). Simply use those identifiers in the above code .custom() for MRE.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can determine the size (height) needed to display your text before drawing

Comment: Another option is to reduce the size to fit https://stackoverflow.com/q/61427991/2303865

Comment: Don’t set hardcoded values, you are basically telling it to clip it.

Comment: @loremipsum how am I hard coding values, I just set it to size 28 and its allowed to take as much space as needed from the vstack which has nothing except a spacer

Comment: Please show a [mcve], and that involves including the two fonts you used.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your example (replacing `font.code` with `"Rockwell"` and `.white` for `textColor`. I don't see any clipping. Are you sure this is all of your code and exactly what you're running?

Answer (score 0):

There was no information about the font that caused the problem, so I wrote the code with any font.
I don't think it's going to make a big difference, but could you test it to see if it works normally works?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {

            Color.yellow
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(Date(), style: .time)
                    .background(.brown)
                    .font(.custom("SF Pro Semibold", size: 28))
//                    .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 28)) // otehr test font.
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 10, leading: 0, bottom: 3, trailing: 0))
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .shadow(radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
        .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the font I used in the original question, seems to be same problem